# How to start needed Activity, when I saved data in file?

Tags: java, android, file

When app starts at first, start Activity with two button: Create File and Settings. Then if I click on button Create File - start Activity where I write text and save in file.
If we have error when file saved - start activity with two button. Else start another Activity with three buttons: Look file, Edit File, Settings.

How organize correct transitions between this Activity and How start activity with three buttons if file already saved?

```
public class MainFirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button createFile;
private Button settings;
private boolean start = true;

private static final String MY_SETTINGS = "my_settings";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_first);

    createFile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.create_file);
    settings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settings);



    createFile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainFirstActivity.this, CreateFileActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
           // MainFirstActivity.this.finish();
        }
    });

    settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainFirstActivity.this, SettingActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    File f = new File(CreateFileActivity.FILE_NAME);
    if(!f.exists() && !f.isDirectory() && start) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainFirstActivity.this, MainWithFileActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        //start=false;
        MainFirstActivity.this.finish();
        Log.e("err", "intent");
    }
}
}
```

**MainWithFileActivity**

```
public class MainWithFileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String MY_SETTINGS = "MY_SETTINGS";

private Button lookFile;
private Button editFile;
private Button settings;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_if_first);

    lookFile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.look_file);
    settings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settings);
    editFile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.edit_file);

    lookFile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainWithFileActivity.this, LookFileActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    editFile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainWithFileActivity.this,CreateFileActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainWithFileActivity.this, SettingActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply check if the file exists. If it does not, hide the `lookFile` button

Add this in your `MainWithFileActivity` `onCreate` method

```
File f = new File(CreateFileActivity.FILE_NAME);
if(!f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) {
    lookFile.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```